# How to get correct result in sum in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using subquery to calcualate sum of alias, but it seem it return with wrong result

my table:

```
itm_code          itm_name            PACKING_STYLE       TOTAL_QUANTITY

3211483       DEODORIZATION              1                      32
3211484       DEODORIZATION FILTER       1                      20
3211485       FILTER                     30                     30
3211486       FILTER-RO 8INCH(S)         30                     30
```

this is my recipe:

```
1. Full box = Integer of(total qty/ packing style)

2. Spare_box: via spare_quantity
   spare_quantity = total_quantity - full_box * packing_style.
   If spare_quantity = 0 => spare_box = 0
   If spare_quantity  > 0 => spare_box = 1
```

this is my query:

```
    SELECT 
         l48.itm_code itmcd
         , l48.itm_name itmname
         , l48.PACKING_STYLE
         , l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY             
         , FULLBOX
         , SPARE_BOX
                    
         , SUM(FULLBOX + SPARE_BOX) AS TOTALBOX 
      from 
         log0048d l48
         , ( SELECT 
                
                ROUND(SUM(l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY / l48.PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX
                , CASE WHEN ROUND(SUM(l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY/l48.PACKING_STYLE) * l48.PACKING_STYLE)) =  0 THEN  0
                       WHEN ROUND(SUM(l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY - (l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY/l48.PACKING_STYLE) * l48.PACKING_STYLE)) >  0 THEN  1
                   END AS SPARE_BOX
            FROM log0048d l48 )
         
     where 1 = 1
       AND l48.reqst_no  = 'SMO21071900398'         
      GROUP BY 
    
        l48.itm_code
        , l48.itm_name
        , l48.reqst_no_itm   
        , l48.PACKING_STYLE
        , l48.TOTAL_QUANTITY             
        , FULLBOX
        , SPARE_BOX
```

and then i received the wrrong is:

```
itm_code        itm_name      PACKING_STYLE  TOTAL_QUANTITY    FULLBOX    SPAREBOX    TOTALBOX

3211483     DEODORIZATION           1             32             58          0           58
3211484     DEODORIZATION FILTER    1             20             58          0           58
3211485     FILTER                  30            30             58          0           58
3211486     FILTER-RO 8INCH(S)      30            30             58          0           58
```

and correct result i expected following as:

```
itm_code        itm_name      PACKING_STYLE  TOTAL_QUANTITY    FULLBOX    SPAREBOX    TOTALBOX

3211483     DEODORIZATION           1             32             32          0           32
3211484     DEODORIZATION FILTER    1             20             20          0           20
3211485     FILTER                  30            30             1           0           1
3211486     FILTER-RO 8INCH(S)      30            30             1           0           1
```

How can i get correct result as my expected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your sample data is not complete or I don't get your requirements but

```
select 
  code, 
  name, 
  packing_style, 
  total_quantity, 
  floor(total_quantity / packing_style) as fullbox, 
  sign(total_quantity - floor(total_quantity / packing_style) * packing_style) as sparebox,
  floor(total_quantity / packing_style) + sign(total_quantity - floor(total_quantity / packing_style) * packing_style) as totalbox 
from thetable
```

should do the job. No need for grouping (especially not by almost every single column of your result, what sense does such a grouping make)

Of course you can make this more readable and better maintainable for instance as follows

```
with 

fbe(code, fullbox) as (
  select 
    code, 
    floor(total_quantity / packing_style) as fullbox
  from thetable
),

sbe(code, sparebox) as (
  select
    t.code,
    sign(t.total_quantity - fbe.fullbox * t.packing_style) as sparebox
  from thetable t inner join fbe on t.code = fbe.code
)

select 
  t.code,
  t.name,
  t.packing_style,
  t.total_quantity,
  fbe.fullbox,
  sbe.sparebox,
  fbe.fullbox + sbe.sparebox as totalbox
from thetable t 
  inner join fbe on t.code = fbe.code 
  inner join sbe on t.code = sbe.code
```

You can also get the value for `sparebox` via the modulo operation, ie if the remainder of `total_quantity/packing_style` is different from `0` you need a sparebox, otherwise you don't. Ie you can write the query also as follows:

```
select 
  code, 
  name, 
  packing_style, 
  total_quantity, 
  floor(total_quantity / packing_style) as fullbox, 
  sign(mod(total_quantity / packing_style)) as sparebox,
  floor(total_quantity / packing_style) + sign(mod(total_quantity/ packing_style)) as totalbox 
from thetable
```

Furthermore, `totalbox` will always be either `fullbox` (if the totalquantity is a multiple of the packing style) or `fullbox + 1` (otherwise), so you can simplify that further as follows:

```
select 
  code, 
  name, 
  packing_style, 
  total_quantity, 
  floor(total_quantity / packing_style) as fullbox, 
  sign(mod(total_quantity / packing_style)) as sparebox,
  ceil(total_quantity / packing_style) as totalbox 
from thetable
```

See the docs for [floor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/FLOOR.html), [ceil](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CEIL.htm), [sign](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SIGN.html) and [mod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MOD.html)

Comment: thank @derpirscher: your advance is useful for me, sorry because i'm not enough  reputation to vote for you, thank so much ^^